# How to set icon for program started using Start command in windows batch cmd

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In Windows 7 (and other versions), a batch (.CMD) file can contain the START command to run other executables without pausing the current batch execution.   (similar to & in Unix). Under normal conditions, the program runs and the CMD file immediately exits.

I'm trying to start an executable from a CMD, and have it behave exactly as if it were started from a direct shortcut.  The basic flow of the CMD script is:

```
   ...{check pre-requisites}... 
   start "MyProg" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram.exe" "Param1" "Param2"
   ...{handle errors}...
```

The Start command is working, but the started executable MyProgram.exe does not have its normal icon on the system's taskbar.  It is the "blank sheet of paper" icon instead of the application's.

Is there any way to set the Windows taskbar Icon to that of the executable that is started?

[Microsoft provides a number of parameters](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true), but none are related to the icon.

Comment: It is a command line program? Does the shortcut you normally use to start it have a custom icon set?

Comment: if you run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\MyProgram.exe"` at a cmd prompt, what icon appears on the taskbar?

Comment: nwk, The program being run is a Windows GUI app (Eudora, the old email client). It has two icons in the EXE resources.    meatspace, that is a good point. I tried running "C:\Program Files (x86)\Qualcomm\Eudora\Eudora.exe" "C:\data\Internet\Mail" "C:\Data\Internet\Mail\Eudora.ini" from a command prompt, and the icon was wrong (the white sheet of paper).  Other Windows GUI apps run from the command line do have their proper icon in the task bar. So something strange about Eudora, maybe?